# getUserMedia() how catch subsequent changes?

Tags: javascript, html, getusermedia

```
navigator.getUserMedia (
   // constraints
   {
      video: true,
      audio: true
   },
   // successCallback
   function(localMediaStream) {
      var video = document.querySelector('video');
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
      video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
         // Do something with the video here.
      };
   },

   // errorCallback
   function(err) {
    if(err === PERMISSION_DENIED) {
      // Explain why you need permission and how to update the permission setting
    }
   }
);
```

Which this code we can check permissons for record in `getUserMedia();`

But how catch subsequent changes user votes for allow or disallow recording video or sound in `getUserMedia()` ?

I.e. when record already underway and user want blocked record(when he again click https://i.stack.imgur.com/T30S7.png).

Comment: Looks like those changes only affect subsequent calls.